# How to locate and click " Sell Something " Button on SELENIUM Python3 ( following my code )

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to click a button on facebook.com/marketplace
but the button has a dynamic id !
I tried starts-with and contains and doesn't work
maybe i didn't know how to use them

Follow my code ( change line 34 and 31 for fb login ) and you'll find the button "sell something" on  the left of screen

```
import time
import os


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pyautogui

keyboard = keyboard.Controller()
mouse = mouse.Controller()

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
  })

# Open Browser and go to facebook logging page
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\Python\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://facebook.com')

email = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
email.send_keys('youremail')

password = browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
password.send_keys('yourpassword')

login = browser.find_element_by_id('u_0_a')
login.click()

browser.get('https://facebook.com/marketplace')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `xpath` with the value `//button[contains(text(),"Sell Something")]//i` and use `WebDriverWait` like this:

```
browser.get('https://facebook.com/marketplace')      

elemt = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Sell Something")]//i')))
elemt.click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually go with a search by XPath instead.

```
   result = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sell Something')]")
```

Notise that you can use another tag instead of div to search on your website.

Also, be careful. This method will return an array. That's because more than one element can fulfill the conditions of the xpath filter.
So if you're searching for an unique element, you'll have to refer to the first element of the resulted array.

```
my_searched_element = result[0]
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: here's a link to some documentation about XPath and other types of search for selenium on python:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: i can't click on it " result.click() " doesn't appear on the list